# Discord.py bot that executes responses based on specific role

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

My python script:

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'X'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!test'):
        msg = "This message is a test".format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

    if message.content.startswith('!admin'):
        msg = "This command can be executed only as the owner".format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

For my discord bot I want to make it so that !test can be used by everyone and the bot would respond with "This message is a test". In addition, I want !admin to only be executed by the owner role and the bot would only respond with "This command can be executed only as the owner" or else it will reply with "Sorry you do not have a permission to use this command". How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you know about the owner role?  It's id, its name, etc...

Comment: Let me rephrase instead of using the owner role, how would I make it so that the command can only be executed when the user has the role "member"?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check if a message came from a server owner, no roles required:

```
if message.content.startswith('!admin'):
    if (message.author == message.server.owner):
        # do stuff
    else:
        msg = "This command can only be executed by the owner."
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Of course, if you do this, you first need to make sure that private (direct) messages do not reach this statement, as they have no 'server' parameter. That can be done like this:

```
if (message.channel.type == discord.ChannelType.private):
    return
```

All of this can be found in the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

Comment: Ok lets say that I want !admin to be used by the role "member" how would I make sure the message author is equal to the role "member."